# Kramdown for atom

Tags: configuration, latex, previews, markdown, atom

I used [Atom](https://atom.io/) to write Markdown. Now I am using [kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/) (mainly for its Latex math support).

How can I change the markdown processor in Atom to be the one for kramdown and enable its markdown-preview functionality for kramdown?

Without any changes, for example, the markdown-preview does not render Latex math in kramdown.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 and Atom 1.0.0.